# Custom Error Validation on Properties do not resolve

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have the following domain class in my Grails 2.4.4. application:

```
class Company {
  String name
   static constraints = { name blank: false, nullable: false }
}
```

When I submit a form without specifying the name I get the following error messages:

```
[
test.Company.name.nullable.error.test.Company.name, 
test.Company.name.nullable.error.name, 
test.Company.name.nullable.error.java.lang.String, 
test.Company.name.nullable.error, 
company.name.nullable.error.test.Company.name, 
company.name.nullable.error.name, 
company.name.nullable.error.java.lang.String, 
company.name.nullable.error, 
test.Company.name.nullable.test.Company.name, 
test.Company.name.nullable.name, 
test.Company.name.nullable.java.lang.String, 
test.Company.name.nullable, 
company.name.nullable.test.Company.name, 
company.name.nullable.name, 
company.name.nullable.java.lang.String, 
company.name.nullable, 
nullable.test.Company.name, 
nullable.name, 
nullable.java.lang.String, nullable]
```

I tried to customize the message using `messages.properties`.

```
company.name=test1
company.name.blank=test2
company.name.blank.error=test3
company.name.nullable=test4
company.name.nullable.error.buddyis.Company.name=test5
company.name.nullable.error=test6
company.name.nullable.error.name=test7
company.name.nullable.name=test8
company.name.null=test9
company.name.null.error.buddyis.Company.name=test10
company.name.null.error=test11
company.name.null.error.name=test12
company.name.null.name=test13
```

None of the former custom error messages where resolved.

**What do I have to do to get custom error messages for blank and nullable being resolved?**

Comment: `com.whatever.package.ClassNameGoesHere.propertyInBeanForm.nullable` for `nullable` for example, use `.blank` for `blank`.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore My package is test my class Company. What is property in Bean form?

Comment: Bean form means, bean naming convention. So typically what you would use as the actual property name in your class. So given your example class your message code should be: `test.Company.name.nullable`

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I tried this but it does not work

Comment: Then something else is going on because I have a test project running right now with this exact configuration and it's working as expected. In fact you can see it's trying to resolve to `test.Company.name.nullable`. You may need to `clean` your app.